# Can you use something like a polarising material to shift an image horizontally?

Tags: polarization, vision, visualization

A while ago I saw a video that I can’t recall about about some patterns being shifted horizontally with material that causes a polarising effect, I just want to know if that is true? Is it possible to take 2 or more materials that cause the polarising effect and cause an image to be shifted along an X or Y axis? Instead of just changing the opaque levels.

Thank you for reading I hope you have an input

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking of a calcite crystal which is [doubly refracting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence).  The calcite has two fairly different indexes of refraction depending of the polarization of the incident light.  For a light source that produces unpolarized light this leads to two images being produced.  For any angle of incidence greater than 0 degrees both images would be shifted but not by the same amount leading to a double image.  The shifting in this case is not really a result of the polarization but rather just a result of the refraction.  The reason the images are shifted is the same reason a regular glass prism would shift an image.

Comment: That makes more sense thank you. I don’t have karma to uptick it